# Timing issue: rendering elements on the page via javascript, need to call those elements in the same file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, coffeescript

I have this code in my CoffeeScript file. Basically, I'm waiting for a response from a click event to populate a bunch of `li`'s with content. **But then I need to grab those elements with jQuery and handle another click event**

As the code currently stands, the bottom jQuery isn't working since the elements aren't on the page.

Any help would be really appreciated!

```
$ ->
      chrome.tabs.query("active": true, "currentWindow": true,
      (tab) -> 
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, "showTerms", 
          (response) ->
            console.log (JSON.stringify(response))
            terms = response
            for term in terms
              $(".terms").append($('<li></li>', {"class": "term", "data-term": "#{term}", "text": "#{term}"} ))

            for child in $(".terms").children()
              $(child).append($('<a></a>', {"href": "#", "class": "remove-term", "text": "x"} ))
        )
      )

  $(".terms li a").click (e) =>
    debugger
    e.preventDefault()
    termToBeRemoved = e.parent().data("term")
    chrome.tabs.query("active": true, "currentWindow": true,
      (tab) ->
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, "remove" + termToBeRemoved,
          (response) ->
            console.log response
        )
    )
```

Comment: Try replacing `$(".terms li a").click (e)` with `$(".terms li").on("click","a"...`. See jQuery docs - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Why? What is the difference here?

Comment: `click` will attach event handlers only to existing elements, `on` will attach event to the parent, but delegate it to the children (even the one that will be added in the future). On the second thought it should be `$(".terms").on("click","li a"...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the click events to the elements when they are loaded:

```
$ ->
      chrome.tabs.query("active": true, "currentWindow": true,
      (tab) -> 
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, "showTerms", 
          (response) ->
            console.log (JSON.stringify(response))
            terms = response
            for term in terms
              $(".terms").append($('<li></li>', {"class": "term", "data-term": "#{term}", "text": "#{term}"} ))

            for child in $(".terms").children()
              $(child).append($('<a></a>', {"href": "#", "class": "remove-term", "text": "x"} ))
           #Bind them here after they've been created.
            $(".terms li a").click (e) =>
              debugger
              e.preventDefault()
              termToBeRemoved = e.parent().data("term")
              chrome.tabs.query("active": true, "currentWindow": true,
                (tab) ->
                  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, "remove" + termToBeRemoved,
                    (response) ->
                       console.log response
                  )
              )
        )
      )
```